# Copied XEN vm to new host - boots up asking to fix the HD (win2003 guest)

Tags: windows-server-2003, centos, virtualization, xen, migration

I have an old box running CentOS 5.4, and XEN.

It has a 2003 Guest that I wish to move over to another CentOS box running XEN. I stopped the machine, and have SCP'd the HD image files of the guest to the new host. I ran md5sum on the files, and they are identical.

When I configure a new Guest, it fires up, but windows fails to boot asking to fix the system instead. The HD are identical, so I'm guessing there is something that I missed. I don't want to go through this procedure, because the system needs to be identical.

How can I get one VM to run seamlessly on another host?

Any ideas, and comments are 100% appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: After some work on this, I found that the files did not transfer correctly. One more Rsync, and After MD5sum to confirm the files, everything worked.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some work on this, I found that the files did not transfer correctly. One more Rsync, and After MD5sum to confirm the files, everything worked. Thank You